# Does ember's dist output require node?

Tags: ember.js

When you build an Ember application the output is placed in the `dist` folder.  Can I take this output and stick it into IIS on a server without installing node?  I understand that during development I need to have node.js installed.  I'm asking if the production host server will require node.js if I'm hosting in IIS?

Comment: No, you don't need node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A built Ember application (the contents of the `/dist` folder) is composed of files that can be served statically, so there's no requirement for node.js.

You should be able to serve them with IIS without a problem, just make sure you configure the routes properly if you're using the history API ([`location: 'auto'`/`location: history`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html#property_location)).